# Attempting to create a single map image from tiles using canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I have a bunch of png map tiles that I am trying to stitch together on a canvas element.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MowgliB/sbzu26py/4/)

I am making a 10x10 tile with a counter from 0 to 99 (`id`) to keep track of where I'm up to. This is the line that plots the image:

```
ctx.drawImage(this, id%10*imgWidth, Math.floor(id/10)*imgHeight, imgWidth, imgHeight);
```

Where `id` is some number from 0 to 99, `imgWidth` is the width of each tile and `imgHeight` is the height of each tile.

I am reasonably confident that should work, but it appears to just plot one stretched tile on the canvas instead of all 100. When I check the console for what was loaded, the images appear to be the correct shape and contents for each tile. The just don't seem to have been placed on the canvas. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason to not use jQuery with canvas:

```
$('canvas').width(imgWidth*10).height(imgHeight*10);
```

:) as this refers to the *element* size, not the bitmap. I would suggest using instead:

```
myCanvas.width = imgWidth*10;
myCanvas.height = imgHeight*10;
```

[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/sbzu26py/5/)

Comment: It's the little things, isn't it? Bloody genius. Now I'll just have to work out why those tiles aren't lining up properly.

Comment: @MowgliB sure is, and harder to spot. I didn't check the rest - but my initial guess is the load order; the images doesn't necessarily finish in the same order they where requested, but since the counter increments mercilessly (?) regardless, the incoming images are placed wherever the current position is.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but because I use the on load event to call for the next tile, it should maintain order. I am thinking this may be caused by the projection I am using. Since it's spherical, using a linear function to determine the next tile coordinates probably isn't the best way to do it. I just hoped that the distances I was covering was small enough that it wouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: Or on second thought, I'm loading the rows in the reverse order. Haha.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you trigger next load from within the handler, that will be more "synchronous" yup, you're right. Some people tend to read maps in reverse anyways :p